# Is there a simpler German saying for "Das Ganze ist mehr als die Summe seiner Teile"?

Tags: phrase, expression, letter, quotes, business-correspondence

I am writing an e-mail to a potential business partner and want to express how our partnership could benefit the both of us. The above saying by Aristoteles came to mind but it sounds much to elaborate for a business context. Is there a similar saying/phrase like this?

Comment: Bei jedem Vertrag gehen beide Parteien davon aus, davon zu profitieren, sonst gehen sie ihn nicht ein. Mit dem Spruch vom Ganzen hat das nichts zu tun. Oft bekommt eine Seite eine Ware oder Leistung, die andere das Geld. Der Gewinn insgesamt ist gerade Summe der Teile.

Comment: "Bei jedem Vertrag gehen beide Parteien davon aus, davon zu profitieren, sonst gehen sie ihn nicht ein" Genau davon, dass beide profitieren, soll das Gegenüber ja gerade noch überzeugt werden. Es hat schon was mit dem Spruch vom Ganzen zu tun, der konzeptuelle Zusammenhang ist hier wie folgt: Die beiden Spieler A und B können jeweils einzeln Profit erwirtschaften, P(A) und P(B). Wenn sie zusammenarbeiten, und wir diesen Profit als P(A&B) bezeichnen wollen, dann gilt: P(A&B) > P(A) + P(B). Der Profit der gemeinsamen Anstrenung ("das Ganze") ist größer als die Summe der Einzelanstrengungen.

Answer (score 7):

Referring the increasing company value

> ... der im Falle unserer Kooperation [auf beiden Seiten] entstehende
>   **Mehrwert** ...

may also be an option.

Comment: ＋１  a really short suggestion. It’s quite a nice word, implying an actual value greater than it’s worth. That, however, is why one shouldn’t use *Mehrwertsteuer*.

Answer (score 6):

## The answer

The usual term in business contexts is *Synergie* - "synergy". It describes a *Win-win-Situation* (also a common phrase in business in german) where both partners profit from joint effort.

## Additional information

Outside of business contexts, in philosophy and often in the humanities, you will find the term "Emergenz", coined to describe exactly the phenomenon that an entity is more than the sum of its parts - see [en:wikipedia: Emergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergence) and [de:wikipedia: Emergenz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergenz).

Answer (score 4):

Your long version could be suitable for e.g a speech after a contract was signed and is celebrated by both parties.

For mail, I would prefer examples like:

> Die Vereinbarung wäre zu unserem gegenseitigen Nutzen.
>
> Die Vereinbarung wäre zu unserem gegenseitigen Vorteil.
>
> Die Vereinbarung wäre ein Gewinn für alle Beteiligten.

Answer (score -2):

I'd check this with a native speaker, but maybe

> Kein Nullsummenspiel

Comment: *[Nullsummenspiel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nullsummenspiel)* refers to something entirely different, namely if the total costs of some endeavour equal the total benefits (or similar).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Even if it is not 100 % accurate, "Nullsummenspiel" does not refer to something *entirely* different. A Nullsummenspiel is a game, where the profits of one player equal the costs of the rest of the players. And a game, where the joint effort of all players results in a net benefit for all cannot be a Nullsummenspiel. Better see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsummenspiel it's better than Duden in this case.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Thats wrong, or more precisely, only true, if the one player only has profits but no costs and the other players have no benefits, but only costs. But the question is about two players in a game with unknown number of total players. But a benefit for both is not at all the meaning of "Das ganze ist mehr als die Summe der Teile".

Comment: @userunknown But look at the question, not only at its title: "want to express how our partnership could benefit the both of us", That's clearly not a Nullsummenspiel - maybe the title of the question is not chosen complettely accurate; Of course, from a game-theoratically point of view, you can take the profits and benefits of other player into account; but regarding the cooperation or non-cooperation of the two partners as a game, it is correct to say that this is not a Nullsummenspiel.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Was kein Nullsummenspiel kann einerseits ein Verlust für beide oder in Summe ein Verlust sein, es kann ein Nettogewinn in der Summe sein aber dennoch ein Verlust für einen, und dass das Ganze mehr ist als die Summe der Teile ist, so wie noch, eine andere Betrachtung, nämlich entgegen der Intuition eine qualitative, keine quantitative.